# login redirect changed after using microsoft.web.helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In an asp.net mvc3 website, I imported the microsoft.web.helpers, webmatrix.data, and webmatrix.webdata.  After that, I have found that when I use the [Authorize] attribute on some ActionResults in Controllers, my redirect points to account\login and not account\logon which is what it had done before and is the default.

I'm not using WebMatrix but would like to use the microsoft.web.helpers functionality.  I've searched in code for any reference to account\login but there isn't any I could find.  My web config for authentication is shown below:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: did you work out this problem ? I have a problem with my Custom Membetship provider. looks like microsoft-web-helpers package is breaking something in authentication system.

Answer (score 8):

To override use:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/Logon" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

From http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/archives/webmatrix-redirects-unauthorized-pages-to-accountlogin

Comment: I have logged this as an issue on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/webmatrix/feedback/details/665150/including-webmatrix-data-dll-webmatrix-webdata-dll-overrides-forms-loginurl

Answer (score 3):

I ran into that same issue some time ago.
I had added a 'deployable dependency' on 'ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax'. This adds a reference to: WebMatrix.Data.dll This assembly has a class with a static constructor that does the following:

```
static FormsAuthenticationSettings()
{ 
 FormsAuthenticationSettings.LoginUrlKey = "loginUrl";
 FormsAuthenticationSettings.DefaultLoginUrl = "~/Account/Login";
}
```

That explains! It will override whatever you had in your web.config.

Answer (score 2):

you can just delete WebMatrix.WebData.dll from you bin file