# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found Membership Provider Authorization Access

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, login-control

I'm using Membership Provider for create and manage users and roles in my site. I'm trying to restric access to a specific roles to the Account folder using web.config into this folder with this rule:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator"/>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I'm using Web Forms and forms authentication like show below:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

But when I try to access to page located into Account folder I'm getting:

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.** Below a picture with the error:

[image]

How can I do for redirect to Login when the user try to access to unauthorized folder or url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `Login.aspx` like `/Account/Login/Default.aspx` which doesn't exist.

Shouldn't that be `~/Account/Login.aspx`?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

### How to debug?

1. Make sure you can access Login.aspx properly.
2. Then paste that URL inside form tag in web.config like above.

Comment: Well, the problem is generating the url path. The site generated /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fUserBasedAuthorization.aspx but isn't putting the extenssion .aspx to Login. I tested putting loginUrl="~/Acount/Login.aspx" and loginUrl="~/Acount/Login" and I got the same error... Another suggestion?

Comment: Where is your `Login.aspx` located at?

Comment: Into Account folder and I add web.config rule <location path="Login.aspx"> <allow users="*" /> for do it public for all users...

Comment: It might be related to webmatrix - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547608/login-redirect-changed-after-using-microsoft-web-helpers Could you add `<add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/Login.aspx" />` to `<appSettings>` and test again?